# Chainlink Price feed Main contract points to Kovan. Why?

Tags: oracles, kovan, chainlink

I'm setting up price feeds with Chainlink.

https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses#mainnet

This page has sections: Mainnet, Rinkeby, Kovan.

Under Mainnet..

Clicking a pricefeed takes me to ..

`ETH / USD  0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419`

https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331

Why is the Mainnet pricefeed URL on Kovan?

Comment: Whats the pair your select? Which service?

Comment: ETH / USD 0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419

Comment: Are you sure? Could you check again? Also, this isn't really a stack exchange question, this is more a question for the Chainlink docs team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not in Kovan. Based on your pair, it directs to the following link.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419